# javascript: find by pattern and replace

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string which looks like: `'[bla] asf bla qwr bla'` where `bla` is unknown. I need to find all occurrences of `bla` (or something else).
I can do it in several commands using js:

```
const s = '[bla] asf bla qwr bla';
const pattern = s.match(/(?<=\[).*(?=\])/)[0]
return s.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'g'))
```

Is it possible to do in one regex?
`bla` is unknown, I know only about brackets. Anything can be in the brackets.

Comment: You need two steps for this, right. 1) Find the value to replace, 2) replace the value.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: And you want replace the contents within `[]` with what?

Comment: with any string, it doesn't matter

Comment: should we replace all 3 `bla`'s or just the on in `[]`?

Comment: we should replace all `bla`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```js
const s = '[bla] asf bla qwr bla';
const r = s.replace(/(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=\])/i, "test");
console.log(r);
```